# Python glob module

Tags: python, file, io

How do I read all files in a directory that end in *.csv or .bck using glob, then print them all to one file?

At the moment I have the following:

```
import glob

path1 = "C:\Temp\eqtests\*.csv"
path2 = "C:\Temp\eqtests\*.bck"

with open('C:\Temp\output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
writer = csv.writer(outf)
   for fname in glob.glob(path1) and glob.glob(path2):
   with open(fname,'rb') as inf:
      for row in reader:
          writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `for fname in glob.glob(path1) + glob.glob(path2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments:

```
for fi_name in glob.glob(path1) + glob.glob(path2):
```

This will take the two lists returned by the two calls to glob.glob(), add them together, and iterate over the resulting list. You current code didn't work because you were using the `and` statement, which is a [boolean operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).